# Как разделить строку по массиву строк-разделителей?

Tags: c#, массивы, строки

Есть массив из элементов:

```
string[] OkElems = {"+","-","*","/","mod","div" };
```

И есть некая строка `x`. Как разделить строку `x` по любому из элементов `OkElems`?

Пробовал `Split(OkElems)`, но так не работает:

```
var x = "5+6*2-1/4"; 
string[] okElems = { "+","-","*","/","mod","div" }; 
var splitedArr = x.Split(okElems);
```

Ошибка в том что Split не умеет работать с массивом строк. Массив символов, ок, а вот строк, не ахти.

Можно ли как то красиво это сделать, не прибегая к деревянному перебору?

Comment: Split(OkElems) должно работать. Приведите пример где это не работает.

Comment: `var x = "5+6*2-1/4";
          
  string[] okElems = { "+","-","*","/","mod","div" };

  var splitedArr = x.Split(okElems);`
 Ошибка в том что Split не умеет работать с массивом строк. Массив символов, ок, а вот строк, не ахти

Comment: @PetrAbdulin, с чего бы это должно работать? `OkElems` это char[] что ли?

Comment: @tCode не char[], и что с того? Работает соседний перегруженный метод. На момент написания вопроса было неочивидно, что этот момент вызывает затруднения у автора.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте [`Split(String[], StringSplitOptions)`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=netframework-4.8#System_String_Split_System_String___System_StringSplitOptions_) так должно сработать:

```
var x = "5+6*2-1/4"; 
string[] okElems = { "+","-","*","/","mod","div" }; 
var splitedArr = x.Split(okElems, StringSplitOptions.None);
foreach(var part in splitedArr)
{
    Console.WriteLine(part); //5 6 2 1 4 
}
```

Просто в перегрузке метода, принимающей массив строк, объявлен второй аргумент ([`StringSplitOptions`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.stringsplitoptions?view=netframework-4.8)). Если при разбиении нужно удалять пустые строки проставьте `StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries`, если нет, то оставьте `StringSplitOptions.None`.